# Auto running bash script on login

Tags: bash, ubuntu, login, profile, unity

I wanted to make a script which ran automatically on login so I put it into the file `~/bash.profile`, but it didn't run. When I put it in bashrc, it ran on opening a terminal.

What I was doing in the script was accessing a file in the pictures folder.
I just added `./script.sh` in `~/.bash_profile`. How to make it run on login?

I'm using Unity on Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: Please post the script here for clarification. You should put things that should happpen on login time in the file `~/.bash_profile` AFAIK.

Comment: Oh, and make sure it is executable; run `chmod +x script.sh` in case you haven't.

Comment: yes the script is executable

Comment: i did tell that it ran in .bashrc

Comment: `~/.bash_profile` always runs when you log in in text mode (if your login shell is bash), but depending on the distribution and desktop environment, it may or may not run when you log into the GUI. How do you log in (e.g. gdm, kdm, text console, …), what desktop environment or session mananger do you use (e.g. Gnome, KDE, `.xsession`, …), and under what distribution (e.g. Ubuntu 11.10, Fedora Core 15, OpenBSD 5.0, …)?

Comment: i log in unity in ubuntu 11.10

Comment: so what shoul i do

Comment: @user1065734 Does this answer your question? - http://askubuntu.com/questions/30931/how-do-i-make-a-program-auto-start-everytime-i-log-in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.profile` and `.bash_profile` are files that are sourced by bash when running as a login shell such as when logging in from the Linux Text console or using SSH. They are not sourced when loading a new shell from an existing login such as when opening a new terminal window inside Unity or other graphical environment. `.bashrc` on the other hand is only sourced for non-login shells, though sometimes distros will source `.bashrc` manually from within the default `.bash_profile`.  One workaround is to change Gnome Terminal to load the shell as a login shell from it's profile preferences, but then that would run every time you open up a new terminal window.  Another option is to add it to the list of Startup Applications as suggested by @jrg.

Comment: ok then, can i add the script in startup application by terminal
like is there any command to add a script to add in startup application

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to [paraphrase from another answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30931/how-do-i-make-a-program-auto-start-everytime-i-log-in), but I'll include all the basics.

You stated that you're using **Unity**, so search
   for and then open the program `Startup
   Applications` in the dash.

Then, click "Add".

[image]

Now, enter in the details of the script:

[image]

*changing my example details with your own details*

Click "Add" and you should be all set!

Comment: i did the same but the script doesnt work properly