# Why if I don't disable nm-applet and xfce4-volumed my startup slows down?

Tags: performance, startup

I'm running Xubuntu 12.04, and after I ran the update, my login started slowing down big time. I've dabbled a little bit with the programs in Settings -> Settings Manager -> Session and Startup, and tried closing and opening these programs, and then rebooting.

Anyways, I narrowed it down to a combination of 2 processes, "Network" (the connection manager) and "Xfce Volume Daemon". Their corresponding terminal commands are:

```
~$ nm-applet
~$ xfce4-volumed
```

If I disable them, and then run them after login is complete, everything works just fine. Is there a way for me to run these commands automatically at start up? I want to maybe write a shell script and save it somewhere, or at least edit the order things happen after login, so the desktop can load before these processes.

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32599/auto-running-bash-script-on-login